# JSDoc 3 conf.json include not working

Tags: javascript, config, jsdoc, documentation-generation, jsdoc3

I am trying to build a project using JSDoc-3.5.5.  I am currently trying to run a test for errors using a small sample of the files for the project.  I manually included a few files in my conf.json file but when I run the test the terminal tells me "there are no input files to process."  My conf.json file is shown below.  If anyone can help me get this to run I would be very appreciative.

```
{
"tags": {
    "allowUnknownTags": true
},
"recurseDepth": 10,
"source": {
          "include": [
             "/home/cordonem/bitbucket/workdir/src/isl/primitives/analytics/isl_analytics_module.c",
         "/home/cordonem/bitbucket/workdir/src/isl/primitives/analytics/isl_analytics_module.h",
         "/home/cordonem/bitbucket/workdir/src/isl/primitives/analytics/isl_calculator.c",
         "/home/cordonem/bitbucket/workdir/src/isl/primitives/analytics/isl_calculator.h",
         "/home/cordonem/bitbucket/workdir/src/isl/primitives/analytics"
      ],
           "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc|x)?$",
            "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
},
"plugins": [
           "/home/cordonem/jsdoc-3.5.5/plugins/commentsOnly"
],
"templates": {
    "cleverLinks": false,
    "monospaceLinks": false,
    "default": {
        "outputSourceFiles": true
    }
}
}
```

Also, as a side note, if anyone knows how to make JSDoc stop trying to read the Makefile that would be very helpful information as well, as the Makefile throws errors when I try to run the full project.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add the input files that should be processed by jsdoc. Here is how i did this in my project through CLI:

I ran this commands from my project's root.

./node_modules/.bin/jsdoc ./src/app/ -r -c ./node_modules/jsdoc/conf.json.EXAMPLE

which is same as shown in [here](http://usejsdoc.org/about-commandline.html), please read the linked document to understand the meaning of everything.

conf.json is same as conf.json.EXAMPLE